# DQL to query type fragments in documentum

Tags: fragment, dql, documentum

I have an object in `docmentum`, this object has attributes and type fragments, I want to query by a type fragment attribute value. My object name is CIC and it has a type fragment called Emision which has an attrribute called receptor, so when I do :

```sql
select * from dfl_cic c where c.emision.receptor = "XXXXX"
```

I get an error, so how I can query by this value ??